Finding non-repeating 9-digit numbers
Suppose that you are asked to find out a 9-digit number, consisting of numbers from 1 to 9 without repeating. Each time you may initiate a guess attempt of the number, and you will get a value of how many digits are correct. For example, if the target number is "123456789" and the guess attempt is "987654321", you will get a "1" as return. During guesses you cannot purpose numbers with repeating digits, that is, guessing "111222333" is invalid.
The problem is to find an optimal strategy with the least expected guess attempt.
Currently I tried to solve this by observation of the simpler cases, like 2-digit and 3-digit, but when the digit number grows the situation became a lot more complex. Also the part of expectation calculation eludes me.
I would really appreciate the administrator to reformat my question so it is more readable.

Obviously the first guess can be anything in an optimal strategy. Based on the response of the first guess, it is desirable to maximize the entropy of the responses of the following guesses.

What is your solution for the $3$-digit case?

Note that the goal of minimizing the expected number of guesses is different than the goal of finding a strategy that guarantees success after a certain number of guesses.

Do you know "Mastermind"? What you ask is just a extension of it. The 9 digits w/o replacement correspond 9 unique colours. Thus you need no white pegs to evaluate a guess, the "1" as result is a black peg for the "5" in correct position. How to continue is well known me think.

@m-stgt: me think not! This is a 9-peg mastermind board with 9 different colours, and different rules to theMastermind game.

@TonyK -- Maybe I used inaccurate words. "This is a 9-peg mastermind board", correct, I called it "an extension" and omited to mention the 9 holes, "with 9 different colours", correct, I called it "9 unique colours" so to express, each of them may be placed once only. So far we do agree. But I can't see (yet) different rules -- pls explain.

@m-stgt: In Mastermind, you can repeat colours in the target rack and in your guesses; in this game, you can't repeat digits. This changes everything!

@TonyK -- "This changes everything!" No, at least not everything. Because there are 9 holes and 9 colours to be placed once only (a restriction that may be agreed also for Mastermind), repeating colours would be unwise. There is one difference (w/o any impact on the strategy), for the evaluation of a guess you do not need white pegs (to indicate correct colour but wrong position), only the black pegs for 'colour in correct position' are needed -- all 'not black' are implicitly to be flagged white.

What were your observations in the small number cases, though?
